# How to parse a string into a List<Dictionary>?

Tags: java, android, list, collections, dictionary

Say you have a string like that:

```
[{"updated_at": "2012-03-02 21:06:01", "fetched_at": "2012-03-02 21:28:37.728840", "description": null, "language": null, "title": "JOHN", "url": "http://rus.JOHN.JOHN/rss.php", "icon_url": null, "logo_url": null, "id": "4f4791da203d0c2d76000035", "modified": "2012-03-02 23:28:58.840076"},{"updated_at": "2012-03-02 14:07:44", "fetched_at": "2012-03-02 21:28:37.033108", "description": null, "language": null, "title": "PETER", "url": "http://PETER.PETER.lv/rss.php", "icon_url": null, "logo_url": null, "id": "4f476f61203d0c2d89000253", "modified": "2012-03-02 23:28:57.928001"}]
```

and need to parse it into a `List`, each of which's items would be a `Dictionary` with parameters and values from the string above.

For example, `List[0].title` would be *"JOHN"* , etc.

Maybe there is some automated way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a JSON array there. You can consider GSON library. 
It converts json to objects in a very simple way.

For eg

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.getType();
    List<Item> itemList = gson.fromJson(items, listType);
```

This code can convert a json into list of items.

Once you get the list, you can iterate through it and get the object. From object you can fetch the value you need.

Hope it serves your purpose.

Comment: Looks great, thanks. Just one more thing. :) How do I fetch the value out of the object? :)

Comment: From the data you have given, it looks like a database entity. Just create an object to represent it. For eg, I have an item object which has summary, so I do item.getSummary(). So, if your data represents List of books, then create a book class with attribute like title/description/language and getters and setters for the same. Then you can say : bookList.get(0).getTitle()

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JSON parser...

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse the JSON String into Java objects.

See this [tutorial](http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/) for an example.

Comment: Looks great, thanks. Just one more thing. :) How do I fetch the value out of the object? :)

Comment: By using the accessor methods.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this answer does not handle all of the array elements (including parsing your Date objects), you should be able to modify and suit your needs.  Just put your text in a file and load it.  Good luck!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Vector;


public class Test {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("data.txt")));
    String data = br.readLine();

    Vector <String> newdata = tidyData(data);
    for (String s: newdata)
        System.out.println(s);
    Vector<Dictionary> myList = createDictionary(newdata);
    for(Dictionary d: myList)
    {
        System.out.println("Title: " + d.title);
    }
}

public static Vector<Dictionary> createDictionary(Vector<String> indata)
{
    Vector<Dictionary> returnValue = new Vector<Dictionary>();
    for (String s: indata)
    {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
        String key = null;
        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            key = st.nextToken();
            System.out.println("key: " + key);
        }
        returnValue.add(new Dictionary(key));
    }
    return returnValue;
}

public static class Dictionary
{
    public static String title;
    public static String description;

    public Dictionary(String indata)
    {
        title = indata;
        description = indata;
    }
}

public static Vector<String> tidyData(String data)
{
    data = data.replace('\"', ' ');
    data = data.replace('[', ' ');
    data = data.replace(']', ' ');
    Vector<String> returnValue = new Vector<String>();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data, "}");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String token = st.nextToken();
        token = token.replace('{', ' ');
        token = token.replace('}', ' ');
        if (token.startsWith(","))
            token = token.replaceFirst(",", " ");
        token = token.trim();
        returnValue.add(token);
    }
    return returnValue;
}

}
```

Comment: cool, I like the GSON answer above. Here's the alternative by monkeys who haven't used it before! Also, this will work in both Java and Android with no added libraries... ;)

Answer (score 0):

String.split(","); will give you an which will contain the key and value.And then do a split on the individual string of the array using ": " which will again give a array and you can create a dictionary object from it.

Comment: This is the last option one could think of..!!..Why shouldnt use a JSON parser to acheive this..!!

Comment: except the dates will also be split!