# BigQuery - How to parse a string list of dictionary?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

How can I parse a string `list of dictionary` in BigQuery?

- Sample: `'[{"Type":value, "ID":value, "Amount":value} ,{"Type":value, "ID":value, "Amount":value}]'`

May look similar to [`1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72395750/how-to-get-values-from-a-string-dict-list-in-sql-bigquery) and [`2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199823/how-to-convert-stringified-array-into-array-in-bigquery) but naively using `ARRAY`, `SPLIT`, or [`JSON_QUERY`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions)  wouldn't work since the dictionaries have commas.

c.f. other than BigQuery solutions
(Python:[`3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72666850/how-to-parse-list-of-strings-to-dictionary), Java:[`4`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583878/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-listdictionary))

#### Tried

```
WITH
logs AS (
    SELECT '[{"Type":value, "ID":value, "Amount":value} ,{"Type":value, "ID":value, "Amount":value}]' as inventory,
)
SELECT
    inventory,  -- org
    ARRAY(inventory)  -- try 1
    SPLIT(SUBSTR(inventory, 2, length(inventory) - 2), ',') as inventory,  -- try 2
    JSON_QUERY(SPLIT(SUBSTR(inventory, 2, length(inventory) - 2), ','),'$')  -- try 3
    ...
FROM logs
;
```

Comment: I think your problem is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72395750/how-to-get-values-from-a-string-dict-list-in-sql-bigquery

Comment: Actually it is not. The link is same as `try 1` (`[1]`). When you actually execute the `try 1`, the query will produce an error.

Comment: Oh yeah, although that question uses a string for data, the answer assumes an array... It seems though that if in `logs` you `SELECT JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(...) as inventory` then you should be in the same situation and the answer should work

Comment: Did you mean this? `SELECT JSON_QUERY_ARRAY('[{"Type":value, "ID":value, "Amount":value} ,{"Type":value, "ID":value, "Amount":value}]') as inventory,`

Comment: `SELECT JSON_QUERY_ARRAY('[{"Type":value, "ID":value, "Amount":value} ,{"Type":value, "ID":value, "Amount":value}]') as inventory,` will return `null`.

Comment: Hi @BigQueryData Can you provide an expected sample output?

Comment: My bad, should have been `JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY`... I don't have access to a bigquery sandbox right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you can consider the below query:

```
WITH
  logs AS (
  SELECT
    '[{"Type": "shirt", "ID": 123, "Amount": 1}, {"Type": "pants", "ID": 456, "Amount": 2}]' AS inventory )
    
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(unnested, '$.Type') AS Type,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(unnested, '$.ID') AS Id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(unnested, '$.Amount') AS Amount,
FROM
  logs,
  UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(inventory)) AS unnested
```

**Query results:**

[image]